# Find the maximum out of dictionary or tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to find the maximum value in tuple and dictionary and right now I am doing it using loop but I really want to change the code from loop to list comprehension just as one liner code.

Here is the dictionary that I have and from which I need to extract max.

```
student1 = {First_Name: "ABC", Last_Name: "XYZ", Age: 23}
student2 = {First_Name: "ABC", Last_Name: "XYZ", Age: 23, Address: "TYU"}
student3 = {First_Name: "ABC", Last_Name: "XYZ", Age: 23, Address: "TYUZYX"}

A = {student_One: student1, student_Two: student2, student_three: student3}
```

The max should be student_3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be really nice if you can post your current solution so that I can help you out better but what I am understanding from your question is that instead of loops, you want to use a one-liner code to find the maximum. Here are some of the ways to achieve that.

**Using max function in python**

If your dictionary name is dict then you can use the following code to find the maximum.

```
 max(dict, key=dict.get)
```

OR

```
 dict[max(dict, key=dict.get)]
```

OR

```
 max(dict)
```

**You can also use `operator.itemgetter`**

```
max(dict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

**There is a much faster way to get the maximum from the dictionary in Python**

```
def keywithmaxval(d):
 # a) create a list of the dict's keys and values; 
 # b) return the key with the max value
 v=list(d.values())
 k=list(d.keys())
 return k[v.index(max(v))]
```

**You can also use Lambda operator**

```
max(dict.items(), key = lambda k : dict[1])
```

**For Tuple**

There are many ways in the case of tuple also but the `max` function in Python is the fastest way to find the maximum from tuples.

Comment: Thanks, I just tested  'max(dict, key=dict.get)' and it is working fine. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it is working. Thanks

Comment: sure I will accept the answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @EniGari What Hasnain meant by "accepting" the answer is to upvote and check it as answered.